# What position to use to display DIV under each other

Tags: css, html, css-position

I want to create two `divs` one on top of another. I am looking to make it so that the `div` changes size without overlapping on top of another when the browser is resized.

Example:
[image]

This image shows what I have right now (which is what happens when I resize the browser but works just fine at 100% and doesn't overlap):

[image]

This is the HTML:

```
<div style="z-index: 15; position: absolute; left: 0; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 10px; font-weight: bold; color: #00A0BE;">
                    State-Of-The-Art-Technology
                </div>
                <div style="z-index: 14; position: absolute; left: 0; padding-left: 40px; padding-top: 35px; padding-right: 8px; font-weight: normal; color: #000000;">
                    Our state-of-the-art technology ensures that we provide the finest healthcare. Our practice continuously invests in systems and equipment so that physicians can diagnose problems in the most accurate and efficient manner possible.
                </div>
                <div style="position: absolute; width: 90%; padding-top: 90px; padding-left: 5%; padding-right: 5%;"><hr /></div>
                <div style="z-index: 13; position: absolute; left: 0; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 110px; font-weight: bold; color: #00A0BE;">
                    Advanced Electronic Medical Records
                </div>
                <div style="z-index: 12; position: absolute; left: 0; padding-left: 40px; padding-top: 135px; padding-right: 8px; font-weight: normal; color: #000000;">
                    Our advanced electronic medical record improves patient care and gives physicians all of the important patient information they need in one place.
                </div>
                <div style="position: absolute; width: 90%; padding-top: 175px; padding-left: 5%; padding-right: 5%;"><hr /></div>
                <div style="z-index: 11; position: absolute; left: 0; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 200px; font-weight: bold; color: #00A0BE;">
                    Premier Radiology Services
                </div>
                <div style="z-index: 10; position: absolute; left: 0; padding-left: 40px; padding-top: 225px; padding-right: 8px; font-weight: normal; color: #000000;">
                    Filmless radiology capabilities provide rapid results and allow physicians to view images on an office computer screen within minutes. Our premier radiology services include MRI, CT scan, ultrasonography, nuclear medicine, bone densitometry and mammography. We offer computer-aided diagnosis (CAD), which is a tool to assist the radiologist in more accurately diagnosing breast disease.
                </div>
```

How do I fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to change all of the position: absolute; to `position: relative;`

Once that's done, your paddings are going to most likely need to be adjusted.

Comment: I just figured it out but by the time I realized you answered... LOL

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: relative` to position the div's relative to other elements (i.e. the other divs).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S9tw4/

Comment: I just figured it out but by the time I realized you answered... LOL

Answer (score 1):

use `position: relative` instead of `position: absolute` on the divs

Comment: I just figured it out but by the time I realized you answered... LOL